# Pandas Open Most Recent CSV with Partial Name

Tags: python, pandas, glob

Can I use pd.open_csv to find the most recent CSV file in a directory with a file name beginning with "Recent_Data..."?

i.e. If the directory contained the following CSVs:

```
Recent_Data1a.csv

Recent_Data2bcd.csv

Recent_Datasample.csv
```

...and the most recent one was "Recent_Data2bcd.csv", can I get Pandas to select it somehow? Or is it better to use glob.iglob for this sort of thing?

Comment: i would just use `glob`

Comment: Traverse over the list of files in directory find [identify  latest file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python) and open with pandas and open